# How can you get the right access key to push in my git work to my github repo?

Tags: github

i encountered this problem while trying to push to my account[via terminal, working on a site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw02T.png)

and it kept giving me that fatal error "Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."

i have tried getting access to another SSH key but still not working.

Comment: Have you tried [these](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey)? Is the error only occurs for that particular repo or all repo of your GitHub account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh
This article would help you solve the problem.

- Generate an ssh key
- Add it to your account
- Refresh the project both on github
- On your command line and run the git command again.

Comment: Thanks. after i followed your documentation, i had to remove the git and run git init again and recreate the repo. and i got a mail that my SSH key has been changed. Thanks alot this Documentation actually Works!!

Comment: You're welcome...try to connect your vscode to github so it becomes easier to push at all times